# Hide parent window scrollbar based on iframe scrollbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser, scrollbar, hide

I am using a iframe with fixed height and vertical scrollbar. the iframe scrollbar will only appear if the loaded page height is more than iframe height. My need is to hide the browser scrollbar and only show iframe scrollbar. I know I can hide browser scrollbar with something like  body{overflow:hidden} but this will hide browser scrollbar irrespective of page loaded so that will be a problem. I have tried something like this with javascript and jquery

```
document.body.style.overflow="hidden"
$('body').css('overflow', 'hidden');
```

but not getting it working. please advise

Answer (score 4):

Inside the iframe you can use the below code to hide the browser scrolbar. Here's the JS code to achieve this :

```
window.parent.document.body.style.overflow="hidden";
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
 function yourclickfunction() {
 document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";
 }
</script>
```